# Localization and Address settings disappeared after domain change

Tags: wordpress, 4.7, settings

We recently changed a site url. After the URL change and making changes in the settings file there was an issue loading so I cleared the cache and reset the paths.

Everything came back OK except all of the settings in localization, display settings and address settings are gone and fields just have 1 in them. See the screenshot below.

Has anyone seen this? If there is a way to get them back that would be great. Otherwise I can reenter them. They were all on the defaults for the most part.

Running CiviCRM 4.7.27 with WordPress 4.9.4

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen it - it seems odd because the defaults are correctly defined here https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/settings/Core.setting.php#L124